# Zebra-Color-Style ListViewItem rows GROUPED by text in 2nd column

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

I want to color the background of a group of ListViewItems so I can see the grouping by the values in the 2nd column.

Here is a sample C# code:

```
class Bla
{
    public int col1 { get; set; }
    public int col2 { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Bla> obsListItems = new ObservableCollection<Bla>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        obsListItems.Add(new Bla
        {
            col1 = 1, col2 = 111
        });
        obsListItems.Add(new Bla
        {
            col1 = 2, col2 = 111
        });
        obsListItems.Add(new Bla
        {
            col1 = 3, col2 = 222
        });
        obsListItems.Add(new Bla
        {
            col1 = 4, col2 = 333
        });
        obsListItems.Add(new Bla
        {
            col1 = 5, col2 = 333
        });
        obsListItems.Add(new Bla
        {
            col1 = 6, col2 = 444
        });

        obsListItems.Add(new Bla
        {
            col1 = 7, col2 = 444
        });

        Zebra.ItemsSource = obsListItems;

        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the values of col1 are unique, while col2 has repeating numbers.

Where col2 has values like 111 and 333, the backgroundcolors should become - let's say - green while the rest keeps their background color.

By the way: Of course these are mockups...in the future use, there'll be loads of more ListViewItems with different values, straight from a database and ordered by the values of the 2nd column.

And here's my WPF control:

```
<ListView x:Name="Zebra"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=obsListItems}"
              SelectionMode="Single" Background="#FFC8F0F1" FontSize="16" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Column 1"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding col1}"
                                        Width="70" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Column 2"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding col2}"
                                        Width="90" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

@offtopic: Once I remove this line:

```
Zebra.ItemsSource = obsListItems;
```

it's not working anymore. I thought using ItemsSource="{Binding Path=obsListItems}" would work with the usage of this.Datacontext = this. Anyone know why?

Comment: `obsListItems` needs to be a public Property in order to bind to it. Change it to be public and to use a getter/setter, and your binding should work. As for changing bg color, it sounds like an `IMultiValueConverter` should work. Pass it both the current item, and the list of items, and get a count of how many items in list contain the same `col2` of the current item. If greater than 1, color the row green. Alternatively, set a bool flag on the `Bla` object model itself, and use a DataTrigger to determine background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anyone know why?

You can only bind to public *properties*:

```
public ObservableCollection<Bla> obsListItems { get; } new ObservableCollection<Bla>();
```

Regarding the "zebra" colouring you should be able to accomplish this with a converter. Please refer to the following code sample:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        private static List<System.Windows.Media.Brush> _brushesToChooseFrom = new List<System.Windows.Media.Brush>()
        {
            System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green,
            System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red,
            System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Violet,
            System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Yellow
        };
        private Dictionary<int, System.Windows.Media.Brush> _usedBrushes = new Dictionary<int, System.Windows.Media.Brush>();
        private int index = 0;

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int col2 = (int)value;
            if(!_usedBrushes.ContainsKey(col2))
            {
                System.Windows.Media.Brush brush = _brushesToChooseFrom[index++];
                if (index == _brushesToChooseFrom.Count)
                    index = 0;
                _usedBrushes.Add(col2, brush);
            }

            return _usedBrushes[col2];
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<ListView x:Name="Zebra"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=obsListItems}"
              SelectionMode="Single" Background="#FFC8F0F1" FontSize="16" Margin="0,0,0,10"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:ColorConverter x:Key="conv" />
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding col2, Converter={StaticResource conv}}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Column 1"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding col1}"
                                        Width="70" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Column 2"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding col2}"
                                        Width="90" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm. Also added public to the observable collection. I also had forgotten to add a PropertyChanged method. Everything is fine now.